# Git Reset in VisualStudio : Is --soft equivalent to --mixed here?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I was wondering if I understand git reset and Git for VisualStudio correctly:

My understanding so far:

- VisualStudio does the handling of the Index/Staging mostly for you.
- Hard reset (`git reset --hard`) makes it as if you had never changed the repository after checking out the target commit: Head is reset, changes are unstaged and the files are restored to their original content.
- Soft reset (`git reset --soft`): Leaves the changes staged and the files changed but resets head to a specific commit.
- Mixed reset (`git reset --mixed`): Unstages the changes and Resets the Head to target commit, but leaves the files changed.

So the reason why VisualStudio doesn't have soft reset, but only mixed, is because VisualStudio automatically tracks changed files and adds them to the index. So if you soft-reset, unstaging the changes in the process, but VS immediately re-stages them, you've got a mixed reset.

Is this correct?

Comment: VS has only a small subset of git features in the GUI. For full functionality use git from the command line (and it is much easier to find help/examples for the command line.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware, I am just trying to get a better understanding of git, I realized VS didnt have a soft reset and with my current understanding this must be why. Just trying to fact check :)